# How can I teach my phone not to capitalise "It's" every time?

Tags: keyboard, htc-desire-s, auto-correct, dictionary, text-prediction

I'm using the standard full QWERTY on-screen keyboard on my HTC Desire S, and when typing in to any app it seems that I cannot type `it's` without manually inserting the `'`, which is relatively slow and cumbersome, especially considering many other abbreviations work fine (eg, `c`, `a`, `n`, `t` -> `can't`).

If I type `i`, `t`, `s` then the default word that is presented is `its`, but in the word selection list I am presented with `It's` as a second choice; *always* capitalised. `it's` is not presented as a choice anywhere in the list of suggestions.

The phone seems to only capitalise anything else following a full stop or new line, and gets many other abbreviations correct, so why the misbehaviour for `it's`? And how do I fix it?

I've already tried adding `it's` to the dictionary (and checked that `It's` isn't there), but that didn't work.

Comment: That's...odd. I've never seen that before.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that asking this question has encouraged me actually make a proper effort to poke around the phone's settings enough to find a workable solution, which is to enable `Spell correction` for the QWERTY keyboard word suggestions / predictions.

The option is enabled in the location:

- Settings
- Language & Keyboard
- Touch Input

- Text Input

  - `QWERTY` section

    - Spell correction

Now, typing `i`,`t`,`s` mid sentence will produce the suggested words `its`, `Its`, `it's`, which is pretty much acceptable for me. `it's` might be third, but it's *listed* and that's what counts!

I *don't* know if this is a common problem or if the default setting for `Spell correction` is on or off, so I don't know what the *cause* of the problem was, but at least it's sort of fixed.

Comment: check your user dictionary, perhaps you have the capitalized "It's" in your user dictionary?

Comment: @Lie Ryan: It is stated in the question that it is not.